# What is the meaning of the data-pa-click

Tags: html

Can anyone explain me this code:

```
<a href="#" id="signup-button" data-pa-click="header|signup" class="btn btn-small btn-signup">
    Sign Up
</a>
```

Comment: data-pa-click appears to have something to do with PayPal. I did a search using `data-"pa-"click html -pennsylvania` (you might not need -pennsylvania if you're not in the United States, where PA is the two-letter designation for the state).

Comment: It's a data attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Answer (score 0):

Well there is seleveral parts to explaining this code so not sure what you want, so i covered it all as best as i can.

1. You have the 'a' this is known as an anchor tag in html and when the browser reads it, it knows that it needs to anchor a hyper link to another document on this element.
2. the 'id="sign-up" used to give a unique identifier to the element for use with javascript to bind events and methods to it.
3. The "data-pa-click="header|signup"" is what is known as a data attribute of that element and is used to store data on that element that could be use javascript functions. If you want more information on this link [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-%2A) can give you more information.

   4. The "class="btn btn-small btn-signup"" item is reference to css classes that have been written to style the element. This very much resemebles the ones used in boostrap.

You then have the text in between the tags, that is used as the display text on when rendering the element.

I hope that helps if you are looking for specifics then please comment below and i can update my answer accodingly

Comment: No problem please mark as an answer if you are happy with it 